Why can't I see the jank frames in Flutter DevTools while experiencing janky UI?
I'm trying to debug a janky Flutter app using Flutter DevTools. I am new to DevTools and experiencing a confusion when dealing with the frame chart. While profiling the app, I can clearly see the jank in the UI, but not a single jank frame in the frame chart in DevTools.
I've created a sample Flutter app to demonstrate the problem. The app has a ListView and an artificially added jank that happens each time when a list item goes out of the screen due to scrolling. After launching the app in Profile mode on my iPhone, I slowly drag the list upwards and clearly observe janky UI just like I expect. However, I'm not able to see any kind of indication of jank in DevTools. In fact, the slowest frame that I could see in the chart was about 7 ms.
I have to mention that I'm able to get some red frames in the chart if I scroll abruptly enough, but that doesn't give me a hint why there are no red frames when I'm dragging the list slowly.
Here's the sample code:
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late final ScrollController _scrollController;
  int _currentFirstVisibleIndex = 0;

  void _onScroll() {
    double scrollOffset = _scrollController.offset;
    const itemHeight = 66.0;
    final newFirstIndex = scrollOffset < itemHeight
        ? 0
        : (scrollOffset / itemHeight).ceil();
    if (newFirstIndex == _currentFirstVisibleIndex) {
      return;
    }
    _currentFirstVisibleIndex = newFirstIndex;

    // Artificial jank:
    _fibonacci(40);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.removeListener(_onScroll);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 16.0,
            vertical: 12.0,
          ),
          child: Text(
            'Item $index',
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ),
        itemCount: 100,
        separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(
          thickness: 0,
          indent: 12,
          color: Colors.black87,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

int _fibonacci(int n) {
  if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
    return n;
  }
  return _fibonacci(n - 1) + _fibonacci(n - 2);
}

